# PHP - как вывести массив попарно?

Tags: php

Есть массив

> Array ( [0] => 3 [1] => 13 [2] => 21 [3] => 27 [4] => 102 [5] => 108
>   [6] => 117 [7] => 123 [8] => 133 [9] => 177 [10] => 188 [11] => 195
>   [12] => 239 [13] => 245 [14] => 254 [15] => 260 [16] => 266 [17] =>
>   274 [18] => 281 [19] => 299 [20] => 303 [21] => 312 [22] => 317 [23]
>   => 334 [24] => 346 [25] => 363 [26] => 373 [27] => 381 [28] => 386 [29] => 396 [30] => 408 [31] => 421 [32] => 435 [33] => 454 [34] =>
>   460 [35] => 476 [36] => 483 [37] => 489 [38] => 495 [39] => 501 [40]
>   => 646 [41] => 657 [42] => 664 [43] => 668 [44] => 679 [45] => 684 [46] => 693 [47] => 701 [48] => 709 [49] => 717 [50] => 728 [51] =>
>   734 [52] => 737 )

Как вывести попарно значения массива?
Чтобы получилось на выходе, например: 3-**13**, **13**-21, 21-27, 27-102 и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

Простой цикл:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < count($arr); ++$i) {
    echo "{$arr[$i-1]} - {$arr[$i]}\n";
}
```

`array_map` по срезам:

```
$res = array_map(function($a, $b) {
    // echo "$a - $b\n";
    return [$a, $b];
}, array_slice($arr, 0, -1), array_slice($arr, 1));
```

> ```
> 1 - 2  
> 2 - 3
> 3 - 4
> 4 - 5
> ```